# Python memory error Save split csv python

Tags: python, csv, salesforce

I have all the data of a lead object from salesforce by python and I save it by csv.
but since there is a lot of information I get `python memory error`
.

`**This code get python memory error code**`

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import os
import json
import account

SALESFORCE_USERNAME = '123'
PASSWORD = '123'
SECURITY_TOKEN = '123'

def main():
    # Authentication settings
    sf = Salesforce(username=SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
                    password=PASSWORD,
                    security_token=SECURITY_TOKEN)

    # Lead Column setting to be acquired
    columns = [
        "CreatedDate"
    ]
    sosl = 'SELECT {0[0]} FROM Lead'.format(
        columns)

    # Data acquisition with SOSL
    data = sf.query_all(sosl)

    # Delete CSV file if it exists
    output_csv = 'output.csv'
    if os.path.exists(output_csv):
        os.remove(output_csv)

    # Write to CSV file
    for k, v in data.items():
        if type(v) is list:
            with open(output_csv, 'w', newline="") as f:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns)
                writer.writeheader()
                for d in v:
                    data = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
                    del data['attributes']
                    writer.writerow(data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That's why when there are more than 1000 lines in the csv I want
csv are recorded as follows.

```
1 output1.csv (1000 row)
2 output2.csv (1000 row)
3 output3.csv ......
```

And I get the following error, what do I need to do so that I can get out this way?
I want to split the cvs and I put in with open csv
`iterator = True, chunk size = 1000`

Code

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import os
import json
import account

SALESFORCE_USERNAME = '123'
PASSWORD = '123'
SECURITY_TOKEN = '123'

def main():
    # Authentication settings
    sf = Salesforce(username=SALESFORCE_USERNAME,
                    password=PASSWORD,
                    security_token=SECURITY_TOKEN)

    # Lead Column setting to be acquired
    columns = [
        "CreatedDate"
    ]
    sosl = 'SELECT {0[0]} FROM Lead'.format(
        columns)

    # Data acquisition with SOSL
    data = sf.query_all(sosl)

    # Delete CSV file if it exists
    output_csv = 'output.csv'
    if os.path.exists(output_csv):
        os.remove(output_csv)

    # Write to CSV file
    for k, v in data.items():
        if type(v) is list:
            with open(output_csv, 'w', newline="",iterator=True,chunksize=1000) as f:
                writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=columns)
                writer.writeheader()
                for d in v:
                    data = json.loads(json.dumps(d))
                    del data['attributes']
                    writer.writerow(data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test/test5.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/test/Documents//test5.py", line 36, in main
    with open(output_csv, 'w', newline="",iterator=True,chunksize=1000) as f:
TypeError: 'iterator' is an invalid keyword argument for open()
```

With this way I think that I will not get python error if there is another way they can teach me?

If anyone knows, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = sf.query_all(sosl)
```

This call retrieves all information into memory for the given query, which is *SOQL*, not *SOSL*.

Instead, use

```
data = sf.query_all_iter(sosl)
```

and iterate over the resulting iterator instead of `data.items()`, which will be much more memory-efficient as it won't attempt to retrieve all items at once.

Comment: Thank you for message. 
I tried but I got this error. sorry I don't understand much about this error.

```File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test4.py", line 67, in <module> main()```

 ```File "c:/Users/test/Documents/test4.py", line 54, in main```
   ``` for k, v in data.items():```
```AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'items'```

Comment: If you are following my answer, you shouldn't be calling `.items()`. Iterate over `data`.

Comment: There is an example in the [simple_salesforce documentation](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce).

Comment: Thank you !! I could with this and I no longer get an error. but I don't get the csv file.

```for v in data:```

Comment: Is another question,CreatedDate can you change UTC to JTS Time zone change in python? Right now I get UTC. If you know about this, can you help me?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842231/utc-a-jts-time-zone-change-in-python